# Where are GTK+ icons stored?

Tags: 11.04, gtk

I would like to know where are the GTK+ Themes icons stored?For example, where are the ambiance theme GUI icons stored?(Like the go back, go up, search icons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user added icons are in the user's home folder in a hidden folder:

- home/user/.icons

The installed icons through APT aswell as the defualt icons are in:

- usr/share/icons

The first can only be used by the user that has them, the second can be used system wide.The icons you mentioned for example are in the Humanity folder under usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/XX (xx=size) most are in the 48 size folder and are in both .png and svg file formats and some other in ubuntu-mono-dark.

To edit them you need to use `gksu`

Comment: You should not edit them. If you want to make a custom theme, you should do so under ~/.icons/Theme/ rather than in /usr/share/icons/Theme/.

Comment: Why not?, nothing breaks out of editing the icon.

Comment: Sure things break. The theme, for one. If you change the icon to be something else, and it isn't consistent with the rest of the theme, for example. And if you change it to "fit" the design of an app you're trying to write, it will break other applications that are different from your design. And if there's an update to the theme, you will lose the changes.

Comment: Sure that but i meant break as in an nuclear disaster would happen besides the zombie dinosaurs returning from hell to eat us all if he changed one icon, or an unbootable system. However creating a custom icon set in usr/ has no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

The Ambiance icons (actually, Humanity + mono icons) are stored mostly in the Humanity and ubuntu-mono-dark themes.

Comment: which are located in......?? :)

Comment: They are under the /usr/share/icons/ directory structure. But you shouldn't edit them in place there if that's what you want to do. And if you're looking to copy them into your own app for use, you really should just use the appropriate icon names instead. Also, any copying of any icons does need to properly follow the rules of the licensing which they are released under.